# Authenticate in config file?

Tags: redis, twemproxy

I am using twemproxy for redis and already registered in RedisToGo.com. There is a similar link to my account :

```
redis://user:pass@grideye.redistogo.com:9478
```

But twemproxy does not support this form. What should I do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't supported in the stable version. There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/issues/37) regarding auth support for Redis, and there is also a [pull request](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/pull/81) which patches it in. But apparently, the author hasn't found time to properly merge it into his code yet.
If you are up to it, you can get the code, merge it yourself, and compile it.

Comment: tnx. Yes I saw that pull request and also sent a comment there... I am waiting for the stable version

Comment: @SoroushKhosravi Are you familiar with Linux and C? You can pull the code and the pull request, and merge it yourself, and try building it. Seeing as this functionality is pretty standard, I won't be too concerned about the stability if it simply works.

Comment: Yes I am. I think you are right and I will build the unstable branch and I will report the usage on the github. Thanks in advance.